# Managing a dev vs production environment for a web app?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, project-management

I have finished developing the core of a web application I have been working on.  Since I was the only developer I just developed locally (lamp stack) without using version control (probably stupid but anyway..).  Now that it is getting close to production ready, I have a couple other developers working with me so I set up a repository for my code.

This is my question: I still want to be able to test any changes locally first before posting to production.  How do I manage this with a repository without having to maintain 2 versions of my code (that I have to synch up manually)?  For one, the production code has a few differences here in there (such as database constants etc.).  I'd like to be able to change my code in my local repository, test it on my local apache server, then check the code directly into production (is this even possible using eclipse)?

I am using eclipse and subversion (php code).  I know I asked many questions but hopefully you get the idea of what I am trying to do...and I assume its rather common.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a few things

1. Use tags/branches in SVN. When the code is production ready, tag it with a unique  name.
2. Set up a staging area for integration testing. After a release is tagged for staging, yank it from your vcs and copy it into the staging area. This can be as simple as a different directory tree or a second install of your server.
3. Put constants into separate files that can copied/merged over into the staging and deployment directories
4. Test the staged version against dev to insure everything works as it did in your dev environment. I would point staging to production databases when I am sure it is working and ready to be promoted. Test that it also works against prod.
5. Once everything works in staging, update the production copy. I would suggest you create a clean deployment directory then copy that entire deployment over to the production server after copying/merging config settings.

This was my approach is dealing with perl/cgi many years ago and it worked pretty well. SVN handles tags/branching much better so it should be easier to deal with. We had very few production problems once we started staging the files before pushing to prod.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answers you've gotten already, I'd like to emphasize that if there are differences between your dev and production *code,* you're adding risk.  You should be using the same, well-tested code in both locations; any difference between the environments should be expressed in configuration files.  Any configuration files in source control should be samples only; your deployment script should not push new configuration files to production.

This, in combination with tagged releases and a staging environment that mimics production, should help you promote your code smoothly to the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't created any branches or tags, and probably have a "trunk" that isn't labeled as such.  Best practices would dictate that you have a trunk for the current stable code, branches that you develop against, and tags that are actually used on the production site.  There is a [short description and diagram on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29#Branching_and_tagging).

Of course, that's just best practice.  Your project sounds small enough that you could get away with splitting your code into a development/ directory and a production/ directory in your code repository.  Checkin code to the development directory, and once a change is fully tested, merge it into the production directory.

Whether you do it the right way or the easy way, it's important to do **something** to separate your development code from your production code.  As you add more developers, it will be increasingly unlikely that the development code base is stable because people are checking in code that hasn't been fully tested, isn't complete, whatever.  Spending a little extra time on managing two branches of code will save you a lot of headaches later on.